# Only last image is uploading while trying to upload an array of images in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload an array of objects to my laravel db, one of the properties of the objects in the array (backgroundImgRaw) has a file.

I have to loop through the array to upload all images and get the file name so as to save to db. But only the last file gets uploaded and the name is returned for all iteration.

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
...

foreach ($request->slides as $slides) {
   $backgroundImg = null;

   if (isset($slides['backgroundImgRaw'])) {
       $img_ext = $slides['backgroundImgRaw']->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $img_name = Str::slug($request->user['name'], '-') . '_img_' . time() . '.' . $img_ext;
       $slides['backgroundImgRaw']->storeAs('public/images/' . $request->user['email'], $img_name);
       $backgroundImg = env('CUSTOM_URL', false) . '/storage/images/' . $request->user['email'] . '/' . $img_name;
       Log::info(json_encode($backgroundImg->getoriginalfilename(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
   } else {
       $backgroundImg = $slides['backgroundImg'];
   }
}

$slide = Slide::create([
   'slide_type' => isset($slides['subType']) ? $this->getSlidetype($slides['subType']) : null,
   'layout_type' => $slides['type'],
   'survey_id' => $request->surveyId,
   'background_color' => isset($slides['backgroundColor']) ? $slides['backgroundColor'] : null,
   'background_imageURL' =>  $backgroundImg,
   'screenshot' => $slidescreenshot,
   'text_color' => isset($slides['textColor']) ? $slides['textColor'] : null,
   'button_background' => isset($slides['buttonBackground']) ? $slides['buttonBackground'] : null,
   'button_text_color' => isset($slides['buttonTextColor']) ? $slides['buttonTextColor'] : null,
   'main_text' => $mainText,
   'button_text' => isset($slides['btnText']) ? $slides['btnText'] : null
]);

...
}
```

Only the last image is uploaded. But the rest of the create function works perfectly.

`$request->slides` returns an array in this format

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "2",
        "backgroundColor": "#203661",
        "backgroundImg": "blob:http:\/\/localhost:3000\/4089c09c-caeb-4121-a2a3-9d7aaf20264d",
        "backgroundImgRaw": {},
    ...
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "type": "1",
        "backgroundImg": "blob:http:\/\/localhost:3000\/bc13e931-cb0a-425a-b3c6-2db6dbbdd5a4",
        "backgroundImgRaw": {},
    ...
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you show us the value `$request->slides` is returning?

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen I have updated the question to show what `$request->slides` returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having a similar issue the problem is with the `$img_name` variable, time() goes down to the second so all the images were processed within the same second, so new images just keep overwriting previous images. I have updated the line to:

`$img_name = Str::slug($request->user['name'], '-') . '_img_' . str_random(10) . '.' . $img_ext;`

Comment: `str_random(10)` could also be replaced with something like `uniqid()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php. `str_random(10)` should be pretty likely to be unique (large pool), but `uniqid()` should guarantee it.

Answer (score 0):

Only last image is saving because you put the `create` outside the `foreach` loop. You must put it inside the loop.

I also noticed that you are using `time()` to generate random image name. This is not the ideal way to do it because your code is executing so fast that all of the slide is generating the same `time()`. You can use Laravel's `Str::random` function.

Here are my suggested code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
...
DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
...

foreach ($request->slides as $slides) {
   $backgroundImg = null;

   if (isset($slides['backgroundImgRaw'])) {
       $img_ext = $slides['backgroundImgRaw']->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $img_name = Str::slug($request->user['name'], '-') . '_img_' . Str::random(6) . '.' . $img_ext;
       $slides['backgroundImgRaw']->storeAs('public/images/' . $request->user['email'], $img_name);
       $backgroundImg = env('CUSTOM_URL', false) . '/storage/images/' . $request->user['email'] . '/' . $img_name;
       Log::info(json_encode($backgroundImg->getoriginalfilename(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
   } else {
       $backgroundImg = $slides['backgroundImg'];
   }

   $slide = Slide::create([
      'slide_type' => isset($slides['subType']) ? $this->getSlidetype($slides['subType']) : null,
      'layout_type' => $slides['type'],
      'survey_id' => $request->surveyId,
      'background_color' => isset($slides['backgroundColor']) ? $slides['backgroundColor'] : null,
      'background_imageURL' =>  $backgroundImg,
      'screenshot' => $slidescreenshot,
      'text_color' => isset($slides['textColor']) ? $slides['textColor'] : null,
      'button_background' => isset($slides['buttonBackground']) ? $slides['buttonBackground'] : null,
      'button_text_color' => isset($slides['buttonTextColor']) ? $slides['buttonTextColor'] : null,
      'main_text' => $mainText,
      'button_text' => isset($slides['btnText']) ? $slides['btnText'] : null
   ]);
}

...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no that's not the solution, `create` is inside the foreach loop. See answer above.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `create` inside the foreach loop? You are only creating the last slide on your question.

Comment: @its_tayo, please see my updated answer. I recommend you to use `Str::random` to generate random string.

Comment: `create` is already inside the foreach loop. Yes `Str::random` works. Thanks

Comment: Please mark my answer as best answer if you found it helpful. Thanks